# How to assign default property value for IN parameters in teradata stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

Need to develop a stored procedure to insert values into a table. Consider the table has 5 columns, where not all columns values are mandatory for user inputs. The DDL for stored procedure will be like

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_INFO

```
     (IN EMPLOYEE_NUMBER CHAR(10),
      IN EMP_DEPT CHAR(3),
      IN PHONE_NUMBER CHAR(4),
      IN JOB CHAR(8),
      IN ELEVEL SMALLINT)
```

Begin

--- Insert query here ---

End

This procedure can be execute using commands

CALL UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_INFO(1,'',1234567890,'admin','')

However,columns EMP_DEPT and ELEVEL are not mandatory fields to have values. How can I mention in stored procedure call to take default values like below.

CALL UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_INFO(1,DEFAULT,1234567890,'admin',DEFAULT).

Basically, I want to achieve something kind of this in link using teradata - https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/sqlp/rbafyprocdefaults.htm

Answer (score 2):

There are no optional parameters.  All parameters are mandatory.  So you would probably have to pass in optional paramters as null and then write some conditional logic into your stored proc based on whether the parameter is null.

For example:

```
CALL UPDATE_EMPLOYEE_INFO(1,NULL,1234567890,'admin',NULL)
```

The Teradata documentation says:

> **Rules For Specifying Input And Output Parameters**
>
> Call arguments consisting of input and output parameters must be
>   submitted with a CALL statement. No default parameter values can be
>   defined at the time a procedure is created; the CALL returns an error
>   if the required call arguments are not specified.

https://info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1146-160K/cum1472240816735.html